# ClassNotFoundException weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTSConnection with default persistence provider?

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, jpa, weblogic

I'm a newbie to EE and I'm working on an application on Weblogic 12c. Data Source tests fine in the Admin Console. When the EJB tries to access it, it throws this ClassNotFoundException. I've done three hours of research and I know the issue is that some jar is not in the server's classpath, but I can't figure out which one!!! I'm using the default EclipseLink persistence provider and using MySQL Driver. BOTH of these come packaged with Weblogic (according to Oracle documentation) so I shouldn't have to explicitly add them to the classpath. And besides, adding them didn't work. Any other ideas?

Here's the persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="YLE_PU" transaction-type="JTA">         
    <jta-data-source>YLEDataSource</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.yle.studentmodule.entity.Address</class>
    <class>com.yle.studentmodule.entity.Contact</class>
    <class>com.yle.studentmodule.entity.Semester</class>
    <class>com.yle.studentmodule.entity.Student</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.type.default" value="NONE"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Quote from [WebLogic Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13737/third_party_drivers.htm#i1049464):

"In addition to the Oracle Thin Driver, the mySQL 5.0.x (mysql-connector-java-commercial-5.0.x-bin.jar) JDBC driver is installed with WebLogic Server.

This driver is installed in the WL_HOME\server\lib folder (where WL_HOME is the folder where WebLogic Server is installed) with weblogic.jar. The manifest in weblogic.jar lists this file so that it is loaded when weblogic.jar is loaded (when the server starts). Therefore, you do not need to add this JDBC driver to your CLASSPATH."

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In other case,
Check your jdk version and bit

I solved that change to 64bit jdk

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note StackOverflow doesn't work like a discussion forum, it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have comments - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a new question

Answer (score 0):

There can be another situation, that more than one class file (jars) are available at the server, which creates ambiguity. This situation also generates the same error.
My suggestion is to keep only one jar (related to JDBC) at your server.

I resolved the same issue in weblogic 12c with Oracle as DBMS.
In my case I had the .jar file of the Oracle driver inside the `jdk/jre/lib/ext` folder and another one inside `weblogic` folder as well. Removing the driver from the JDK folder solved my problem.